# lost all the links in WordPress after changing hosting

Tags: hosting, phpmyadmin

I am moving my wordpress website from one hosting to another.
i moved my file(from filesmanager) correctly
i export database from phpmyadmin to new host phpmyadmin

Home page working fine (http://prophetmuhammadsaw.com)
When i click on any post this error occurs 
[Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.]

Comment: If one of the answers below did answer your question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I need more details to tackle up what problem are you facing, but maybe these steps can help you:

**Update your links in Wordpress database**

- Go to PhpMyAdmin
- Find the database of your wordpress page
- Go to wp_options table
- Update "siteurl" and "home" with the new url of your website

**Update your permalinks**

- Go to "www.yoursite.com/wp-admin"
- Go to settings > permalinks
- Save settings

Comment: wp_terms i don't have this table in my database, That its responsible for my missing categories, tags and links

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of information here, but when this happens to me it's generally because you may need to add your htaccess. file again and ensure it's set for your hosting environment.

Comment: Thanks for the the answer, It is not related with the database. wp-terms is missing from database. what i have to do with htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Before messing with the database, I'd try adding the two URL related defines to your wp-config.php. This means you can change your site URLs quickly and safely without editing the DB and will probably be easier to debug what's happening. Then you may need to look to either the DB or htaccess as others have suggested. See the related Wordpress docs [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i Think my hosting provider messed with my database, Never take bad hosting

Comment: Ha. Yeah, that's true. I've been using FlyWheel for dedicated Wordpress hosting over the past year and there's simply no comparison to 'non-wordpress' hosts. Other than possibly WP Engine, I won't consider anywhere else for Wordpress hosting now.